# What is the right approach to let an actor ask "itself" in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, self

I am currently looking for a proper way to send a message from one actor to another of the same kind.
At first I tried to ask "itself" (self), but soon I understood that this is not possible. You cant send a message to self and wait for response while it still handles the "waiting" process.

Now my question:

What is the right approach to ask an actor of the same type? SHould I create a temporary actor which I destroy after I used it? If so.. what about the naming (must be unique)!?
Is there any helpfull pattern?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind giving us a use case example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An actor most definitely can ask itself (i.e. with `self ask`). You can't block on the future (with `Await.result`), but you shouldn't be blocking on futures anyway. However, there is little sane reason to do this. Instead of sending yourself a message and getting a response, execute whatever code you use to handle that message directly.

As an additional point, the ask pattern actually does create a temporary actor and destroy it after it is no longer needed. There is no need to reimplement this.